# Windows Phone 8.1 user ID

Tags: runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have a problem with getting User ID but I mean programmatically. Is any chance to get User's Live ID or something like that ? Because I want use trial experience with expiration time but is only one way how to do this. Storing all user's ID's and after installation check their identity. I don't want to use advertisement ID because it is not working in every case. Not every user is using this kind of ID.

So any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

You won't get any personal information without asking the user.

But the windows store features a trial mode with expiration. Check out the topic [on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Dn532253(v=win.10).aspx).

Otherwise there is an overview on [Idendity on Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh750301.aspx) and you can use [WebAuthenticationBroker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn448945.aspx) on the Phone.

Comment: So is any way how to ask user for his live e-mail or somethink like that ? Because WP8.1 doen't support expiration time in trial mode.

Comment: Updated the answer. Ultimately, TextBox was made for entering data. :)